# Swiftui - Syncing @AppStorage data with iCloud

Tags: swift, swiftui, userdefaults, appstorage

I have a test iPhone app where user has scores that keep updating. Currently I use @AppStorage and that works great. Issue is, if I create iPad app the data won't sync.

I tried NSUbiquitiousKeyValueStore, but it's too slow. Scores don't update instantly even on Local storage.

Is there anything that I keep using @AppStorage and some logic sync data in background with iCloud, so if the person downloads app on another device, data can be synced?

Or some another solution instead of NSUbiquitiousKeyValueStore or @AppStorage.

Comment: "data"? I get the feeling you are using `AppStorage` for more that just settings and insignificant data. Be aware that the intention of this type of storage is for simple things like preferences such as units, volume or playback speed. Data that if it disappears or is compromised would cause an inconvenience and nothing else. It is the most insecure an unreliable type of storage. But to answer your question no `AppStorage` cannot be put in iCloud, `NSUbiquitiousKeyValueStore` is the alternative. CoreData is capable if being connected to iCloud via CloudKit.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Yes, I store game scores as I mentioned earlier. Kindly advise what would be the best way to store and display scores / INT values fast and that can be synced as well. Thanks

Comment: CoreData is likely the simplest form.  You can have public and private storage, synced or local. If I remember correctly there is a specific example in the Apple documentation/WWDC videos that covers “leaderboards” and such.

Comment: @Sunny have you figured out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to store only small amounts of data, like a double value or an array, you should consider [`NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore). It's surely much easier to set up than `CoreData`, which is used for potentially large amounts of data.